# Is a MiKTeX update causing this Qt6Widgets.dll error?

Tags: pdftex, miktex-update

This problem began just after a series of problems updating, when the MiKTeX console advised me that my User update was not synchronized with my Admin update.  But I do not know if it is one problem causing all the trouble, or two problems coming at the same time.  I am using WinEdt 11, Build: 20230519  (v. 11.1) - 64-bit

Now, I get the following error message when I try to use PDFLaTeX or PDFTeXify to compile a document, and also when I try to open the MiKTeX console:

> The code execution cannot proceed because Qt6Widgets.dll was not
> found.  Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

If this is actually a MiKTeX update problem then I do not want to get involved in reinstalling a dll file that I never installed by hand in the first place.  So this question is just to ask if it is an update error.

Comment: miktex switched from qt5 to qt6 a few days ago, and on my system it installed Qt6Widgets.dll in the the miktex/bin folder. Check if the package miktex-qt6-bin-x86 is install (in admin mode).

Comment: Thanks Ulrike, but I cannot open the package manager because when I try to open the console I just get that error message.

Comment: oh well. You probably ignored admin for some time, did you? Well try with the command line tool: https://docs.miktex.org/manual/miktex-packages.html. So e.g. something like `miktex --admin packages check-update` will check for admin updates. You perhaps need a command line with admin rights.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I run user and admin both several times a week.  I will try reinstalling MiKTeX.  I see the uninstall command  also produces this error message.